# Discord bot,without embed, trying to get user roles by user ID,but getting error 400

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
`@client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def burn(ctx ,name=''):
        auth = ctx.message.author
        na = name
        nm = await client.get_user_info(na)
        n = n.get_roles()
        print(na)
        print(auth)`
```

This is the snippet of my code. by /burn @username this code trying to get >@username's roles list by it's id. And then,i have this error
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400)`
How could i fix this?
i'll be grateful for other ways to solve my task.

Answer (score 0):

To get a user's roles you can use [`Member.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.roles).

The following code will retrieve all the roles of the passed user as parameter :

```py
async def burn(ctx, user: discord.Member):
   user_role = user.roles

   # you can iterate through the list of roles like this
   for role in user_role:
      # do something
```

`.roles` returns a `list` of roles.

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def burn(ctx, name: discord.Member):
    auth = ctx.message.author
    na = name
    nm = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m === na, ctx.guild.members)
    if nm is None:
        return #if member isn't found execute this
    n = nm.roles
    for role in n:
        print(role.id)
    print(auth)
```

Something like this maybe? Let me know if this works for you.

Happy coding!